# js prototype's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I've been trying create this simple ish to-do list web app using JavaScript & html5 localStorage for saving the to-do list, so I decided to use obj-oriented programming since it was getting kinda clutter'd with procedural programming, but I can't seem to get it to work, here's a link to the code http://jsfiddle.net/jared/sdPW2/

plus I'm using jQuery to make creating onClick handlers and animations easier.

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - Not telling us what is wrong.

Comment: sorry, if i have console.log('works'); in Todo.prototype.createNew it never gets called so nothing in Todo.prototype.createNew get's called that's what my problem is, sorry about that

Comment: well your jsfiddle says it is using mootools and not jQuery.

Comment: oh, didn't see that, but it doesn't work if I'm just using my text editor and chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see here

First you never call createNew anywhere so how would it be called.

Second look at your code

```
this.createNew = createNew;
```

and

```
Todo.prototype.createNew = function() {
```

Do you realize you have TWO things called the same thing, what do you think happens?